# Should color grading be performed on raw clips, or final sequence?

Tags: premiere, editing, mp4, color, color-grading

Camcorders that record in `.mts` (`.mp4`) files usually split recorded files according to some maximum time limit per clip. For example, after recording straight for 30 minutes, we might find the entire stretch split into 3 separate clips because of a maximum limit of 10 minutes per clip.

Let's say all three of these clips belong to the same scene, and are only disjoint in file structure. In other words, they should be color graded identically. Should color grading be performed on each of the raw clips separately with the same template, or should the clips be merged into one `.mts` file first on which color grading should be performed once?

Answer (score 2):

Grading multiple clips in Premiere is still a bit fiddly compared to something like DaVinci Resolve. If it was only three clips, I would do the grade on one clip, then [copy and paste the Lumetri settings](https://helpx.adobe.com/premiere-pro/how-to/copy-paste-effects.html) onto the other two.

The other option is to use [Master Clips](https://helpx.adobe.com/premiere-pro/using/master-clip-effects.html) in Premiere, where you can apply the correction to the source clips, and then it doesn't matter how many times you chop them up in the edit - they will still have the same correction applied.

The third option is to do use an [Adjustment layer](https://helpx.adobe.com/premiere-pro/user-guide.html/premiere-pro/using/help-tutorials-adjustment-layers.ug.html) over the clips. So you only have to make one Lumetri setting, and apply it to the adjustment layer, then put the layer above all of your clips.

Comment: Between applying color settings to 3 separate clips vs. applying them to the Master layer vs. merging the clips and applying the colors then, which of these 3 approaches is more memory intensive? Would it be inefficient to merge all clips together and post-edit that big film?

Comment: That’s a good question.  I’m not sure. I reckon applying Lumetri to master clips and clips in a sequence probably has the same performance hit. People used to say that (using After Effects) adjustment layers were a more computationally intensive way to process things, but I’m not sure if that’s still true.